# Is it bad practice to have a function return a View (i.e. RecyclerView, TextView) instead of the id to find that View (int)?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-view, android-databinding

So I have a `BaseFragment` that sets up a `RecyclerView`, and many `Fragment`s that extend this `BaseFragment`. I'm also using `data-binding` so I don't have to use `findViewById` anymore. So in my `BaseFragment` I implemented an `abstract` method called:

`public abstract RecyclerView getRecyclerView();`

and in the subclasses, this is implemented as:

`@Override
public RecyclerView getRecyclerView() {
    return binding.recyclerViewLayoutId;
}`

This method is only used in the superclass BaseFragment like this:

`getRecyclerView().setLayoutManager(...);
getRecyclerView().addOnScrollListener(...);`

in the `onViewCreated()` method so I don't forget to do it myself in the 30 or so subclass Fragments (which all need the same thing).

So essentially this is just the same thing as, in one of my subclass Fragment classes, doing:

`mBinding.fragmentSubClassRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(...);
mBinding.fragmentSubClassRecyclerView.blah(...);`

Is this considered bad practice? Should I instead of returning the RecyclerView itself return the id to `findViewById` that RecyclerView?

Answer (score 1):

In general, **NO**. It can cause you [**memory leak**](https://android.jlelse.eu/memory-leak-patterns-in-android-4741a7fcb570) which is a very serious problem to detect and resolve.

In your case it is **okey**, because there is nothing wrong with a `View` to return child views, as the class receiving child view reference already hold the view reference itself.

But a **better** practice would be making these methods **protected** so only the extender class can use the `superclass` methods, this way no one out side the class can gets a hold of View references.

And the **best** practice would be creating a more specific `Class` like `BaseListFragment` and hide the `View`s inside the `Class` itself so in your fragments you can only call methods like:

```
setLayoutManager(...);
addOnScrollListener(...);
```

without exposing View references. of course first you have to set views inside the fragment like this:

```
setRecyclerView(binding.recyclerViewLayoutId);
```

Comment: what do you mean "hide the Views inside the Class itself? So have the class implement some method setLayoutManager and addOnScrollListener so that I can't access the view directly?

Comment: BaseListFragment still requires me to implement some method getRecyclerView, no? Because it's still the Base and all methods that extend it will have different ids from the RecyclerView that is calling this method

Comment: Yes and yes, you have a base class that handles list, right? now the general idea when designing such a components is to first avoid passing view references to outer classes to prevent memory leak. and secondly hide the implementation detail inside your components.
The first one is crucial to prevent errors and second one is practice of good architecture to enable you switch your implementation without affecting the rest of your code.

Answer (score 0):

**No.** but this is my opinion.

From my experience, there is no harm returning the View instead of the id. Even in terms of practicing.